# Учу C++ для разработки под win, но есть желание писать и под андроид. Помогите советом!

Tags: java, android, c++, android-sdk, android-ndk

Знаю `C++`, активно изучаю `winapi`, `openGL` и т.п.

Планирую писать как для `win`, так и серверные части. Но так же есть желание начать писать и под андроид мобильные приложения, но т.к. не люблю распыляется на кучу языков и технологии, подходить к `java` не особо есть желание, по крайней мере сейчас.

Я знаю что есть `SDK` для `java` и `NDK` для `C++`, и логично считать что на том и другом можно реализовать все что захочется.

**Но вот собственно и вопрос:** на сколько колоссальна разница между этими платформами? На сколько проще или сложнее писать на `NDK`?

И суть тут не в производительности (хотя это не лишний бонус `NDK`), а более важнее как будет практичнее.

Зная `C++` начать писать на `NDK`, или все-таки стоит изучить `java` и писать на `SDK`?

Comment: Имхо, быстрее перейти на java, это не займёт много времени. Писать на ndk  требует более глубокого понимания системы андроид. По производительности ndk быстрее только в задачах "числодробилках", ( методы требуют миллионов операций) иначе расходы на передачу параметров (там не все так просто) превышают выигрыш в скорости.

Comment: `Знаю C++` / какое смелое заявление :)

Answer (score 2):

Если Вам категорически не хочется переходить на Java (что является уже неверным путем, особенно при выборе направления разработки для мобильных устройств), то есть куда более удобные решения, чем С++ - это Xamarin на C#.

Переход с C++ на него не очень сложный и всегда будет возможность перейти на Java, если все же Вас что-то не устроит.

Xamarin позволит Вам писать приложения не только под Android, но и под iOS, и под Windows и под MacOS.

Использовать C++ в качестве языка разработки (и технологий, в наличии оного) не является целесообразным, особенно если Вы новичок в этом деле.

Не забывайте, что для каждой задачи необходимо использовать свой инструмент.

Comment: а почему именно `Xamarin`? Что у нас мало движков на с++? Кокос тот же...

Comment: Забивать тапками гвозди - то еще удовольствие. 
Вы точно уверены, что советовать плюсы для разработки под мобильную платформу будет верным решением?

Comment: в вопросе чётко С++ стоит метка... А движок не самый плохой. По мне - лучше всеми любимого Unity.

Comment: А можете пояснить, как тесно приведенный Вами в качестве пример движок, относится к NDK, SDK и Xamarin у C#?
Движок - одно, SDK - совершенно другое.